# Can't get the Plain object from Promise

Tags: mysql, node.js, pug, sequelize.js

I am using MySQL, Node.js, Pug, and Sequelize.

I want to grab data from the database and convert it into a value that can be placed into the variable that Pug can convert to html.

```
    app.get('/', function(req, res){

    var name1 = BasicInformation.findOne({
        attributes: [ 'advisor_name' ],
        where: {
            id: '1'
        }
    }).then(function(name1){
        return name1;
    });

        res.render('programofstudy', {
            advisor_name: name1.advisor_name
        });
});
```

The problem is that nothing appears on the webpage. 
I have tried name1.advisor_name
I have tried name1
I have tried multiple ways of obtaining the information.

I have tried placing the Query inside next too advisor_name:
I am just not sure how to get the value from Sequelize and into the Pug variable.

Comment: Please post the relevant pug template code too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to render the page INSIDE the callback from mongodb:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){

  var name1 = BasicInformation.findOne({
    attributes: [ 'advisor_name' ],
      where: {
        id: '1'
      }
    }).then(function(name1){

      res.render('programofstudy', {
        advisor_name: name1.advisor_name
      });

  });

});
```

Comment: How can I do a ton of grabs and then render from multiple tables?

Comment: The short answer is http://caolan.github.io/async/ - we do it all the time with our routes and pug templates and it works well.  Ask another Question here if you have specific issues with implementing it.

Answer (score 1):

Try with async function :-

```
app.get('/', async function(req, res) {
    try {
        var name1 = await BasicInformation.findOne({
            attributes: ['advisor_name'],
            where: {
                id: '1'
            }
        });
        res.render('programofstudy', {
            advisor_name: name1.toJSON().advisor_name
        });
    } catch (err) {
        res.render('programofstudy', {
            error: err
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: How can I do a ton of grabs and then render from multiple tables?